# Itextsharp and css

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate a pdf invoice.
I have a template for the invoice which is very simple, but uses `CSS3` for the formatting and styling.
 when I display the page in a browser it works fine, but when I try to generate the page into a pdf using itextsharp it seems to ignore all the `CSS3` formatting for some reason.

My question is: Is there a way to get it to work with `CSS`? Or is that a limitation of iTextSharp ?

Comment: Are you using the `HTMLWorker`? If so, that doesn't support CSS, please switch to `XmlWorker` and see this for a list of supported properties. http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm

Answer (score 0):

Are your stylesheets linked with an absolute path or a relative one? PDF converters don't tend to work too well with relative paths.

Comment: I tried both using the relating path "css/styles.css" or the absolute path "http://localhost:8080/css/styles.css" and still both don't seem to work